# Removing list elements

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of type TileToDraw, with this type declared as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct TileToDraw
{
    public Vector2 origin;
    public string type;

    public TileToDraw(Vector2 originIn, string typeIn)
    {
        origin = originIn;
        type = typeIn;
    }
}
```

I have populated this, but want to remove tiles which have a particular origin (vector). Which function should I be using for this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ to create new `List<TileToDraw>` with elements from `sourceList` that satisfy condition:

```
var newList = sourceList.Where(x => x.Origin != myOrigin).ToList();
```

or use [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) method to remove elements from `sourceList` directly:

```
sourceList.RemoveAll(x => x.Origin == myOrigin);
```